# How can I edit the action script within an SWF file?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a rather large SWF file (27Mb) and as a project i'd like to edit the action scripts within it and also change a few images around. Using JPEXS free flash decompiler, I was able to replace the images I wanted. But when I try to save changes to the main script, the program gets stuck on a line that I hadn't changed at all.

```
Line 2788: if(saveFile.data.tableTeacher[this.day] == null)
```

The program pops up a message saying "PARENT_CLOSE expected but COMMA found on line 2788"

Here is a snippet of code leading up to the error line:

```
for(this.day = 0; this.day <= 5; this.day++) 
{ 
    if(saveFile.data.tableSubject[this.day] == null) 
    { saveFile.data.tableSubject[this.day] = new Array(); } 
    
    if(saveFile.data.tableRoom[this.day] == null) 
    { saveFile.data.tableRoom[this.day] = new Array(); } 
    
    if(saveFile.data.tableTeacher[this.day] == null) //# Line 2788
    { saveFile.data.tableTeacher[this.day] = new Array(); } 
    
    if(saveFile.data.tableAttend[this.day] == null)

    .... etc
```

Is there any other way I can edit actionscripts?

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with the provided script. But that's the price for doing things that weren't supposed to be done (which altering compiled ActionScript totally is): it might work nicely, or it might not work at all. 27Mb is a rather huge size for a compiled SWF, no one knows what breaks upon you editing its scripts.

Comment: @Organis Any other way I could see that script changed though?

Comment: **JPEXS** was your best shot. There are other decompilers, but they don't *replace* scripts, they restore source project with, again, no guarantee it will work or can be compiled at all. With 27Mb **SWF**, I think, it will be an unusable mess.

Comment: Hmm. What if i'm able convert it to FLA? Will it then be possible to edit the actionscripts within that file, then reconvert it to SWF?

Comment: Well, you won't know unless you try it, right?

Comment: :D Will do!  :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more code around that block of code.